# Phantom contact record

Tags: contacts, drupal-views

I have a view that displays civiCRM contact records according to Contact Type. The displays needs to change every Fall, and the way we do this is by changing the contact type (but keeping the record).  There is a particular contact record, however, that displays on the view but is missing from our civicrm records. I have looked under his name, email, and contact id, but nothing comes up. This should not be possible: the view displays the contact record's name, bio, university, and image. So how is this person's record displaying if I cannot find him in a search?

Comment: Jon G of Megaphone Tech's answer was correct: "Most likely, the contact is deleted, but your view isn't filtering out deleted users. You may want to check that in your view. You can search for deleted contacts from Search menu » Advanced Search by checking the "Search in Trash" checkbox. "

Answer (score 4):

Most likely, the contact is deleted, but your view isn't filtering out deleted users.  You may want to check that in your view.

You can search for deleted contacts from **Search menu » Advanced Search** by checking the "Search in Trash" checkbox.
[image]